# I can't launch a functional admin website in django

Tags: python, django, module, django-admin, admin

I'm very new to using python and know next to nothing so far. I've been watching youtube tutorials and have been trying to enter a line of code directly from the tutorials but it keeps generating an error. I am copying the code directly from the tutorials exactly as they appear. The line of code that has been generating the error is the following:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('Test_1.urls'))
    ]
```

This code is entered into a `urls.py` folder. Also within the same project, I have a `views.py` folder that reads the following:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Hey, Welcome</h1>')
```

And another `urls.py` folder that reads the following:

```
from django.urls import path
from Test_1 import views

app_name = 'Test_1'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')]
```

When I run the second two lines of code, they work perfectly without any problems. When I run the first line of code, it generates the following sequence of errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jared\PycharmProjects\Testproject1\Test_1\urls.py", line 9, in <module>
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jared\PycharmProjects\Testproject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 266, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "C:\Users\jared\PycharmProjects\Testproject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 595, in _setup
    AdminSiteClass = import_string(apps.get_app_config("admin").default_site)
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jared\PycharmProjects\Testproject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 156, in get_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Users\jared\PycharmProjects\Testproject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 137, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\jared\PycharmProjects\Testproject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\jared\PycharmProjects\Testproject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 82, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. 
You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I tried adjusting the `admin.site.url`s portion of the code because that portion seems to be generating at least one of the errors. I tried adjusting other portions of the code but nothing has worked.

I'm assuming the errors are attributed to codes that are already programmed into the files mentioned in the sequence of errors such as `functional.py` and so on, but like I said, I'm very new to python and have no idea how to adjust those lines of code accordingly. Any advice will be helpful and appreciated.

This is what my project looks like: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBrOX.png

Answer (score 0):

> Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable

You probably forgot to add your app to settings.py. Find INSTALLED_APPS there and add your app name like 'myappname' below all those 'django.contrib...' strings

Answer (score 0):

It's Good you are trying :)

So go into your `settings.py` file, which might be in your main project folder.

There you will find `INSTALLED_APPS` list that already contains some apps, just add your app to that list at the bottom. Please refer below example

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
    # -----Add your app name here----------
    'Test_1 ',
]
```

and one more thing, you can remove `app_name = 'Test_1'` from `urls.py`. That may be causing some problem

Comment: So I went into the settings.py folder and added the name of the app where it says INSTALLED_APPS: 'Test_1' . It still made no difference. I tried entering the name of the project as a whole which is Testproject1 and that made no difference either. I uploaded a screenshot of the project into this forum in case that's helpful. I also tried removing app_name = 'Test_1' and that also had no impact. Idk if this is helpful at all but within the settings.py folder there's a line of code that says: ROOT_URLCONF = 'Test_1.urls'.